# Google AdWords custom conversion tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

We are using AdWords to promote our business and have a customer enquiry form which is tied in to AdWords conversion tracking. Whenever an enquiry is submitted via the form it counts as 1 conversion.

What we would like to do is somehow tie the conversion to the name submitted with the form so that we can later review if this person actually made a purchase and thus determine our ROI.

Is this possible with AdWords and if so where would I have to look to learn how something like that is implemented. I'm willing to hire a developer for this but also assume this is a simple job.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you can do this with Google Analytics by linking the account and adding a custom field in the JavaScript of the tracker. GetClicky does custom goals and fields really well. I think you can do it too by linking together the applications.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Ideally I would like to hear from someone who has already done something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using goal conversion in Google Analytics... more specifically a header match that contains the customer enquiry info i.e. last name.

This is the code used on the form to make it work:

```
onSubmit="javascript: surname = document.getElementById('surname');  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'email/' + surname.value]);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kara, AdWords recently launched offline conversion import.  Read more here...
https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en

If you store the click ID (GCLID) along with your lead information, you can then register new conversions when that lead goes of to do something else like become qualified or converts into a customer.  And best of all, it's available via their API.